# Django redirect not working in authentication

Tags: django, redirect, django-views

I am trying to authenticate a registered user . redirect is not working in my case. after clicking the login button it keep on showing the login page again. i want the user to go to home page upon the successful login. Here are my files.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def register_new_a(request):
    saved = False
    if request.method == "POST":
    # take whatever is posted to the Details Form
        form = DetailsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your account details have been saved!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register_new_a?saved=True')
    else:
        form = DetailsForm()
        if 'saved' in request.GET:  # sends saved var in GET request
           saved = True

    return render(request, 'register1.html', {'form': form, 'saved': saved})

def loginUser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
        # at backend authenticated the credentials
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home') # not working
    return render(request, 'login_a.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name='home'),
path("login", views.loginUser, name='login'),
path("logout", views.logoutUser, name='logout'),
#path("register", views.register, name='register'),
path("register_new_a", views.register_new_a, name='register_new_a'),
path("register_new_b", views.register_new_b, name='register_new_b'),
path("about", views.about, name='about'),
]
```

login_a.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock title %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container my-3" >
<h1 class="display-3" align="center">Login Here</h1>
<br>
<h1 class="display-6" >STEP 1: </h1>

<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="Username1" class="form-label" >Username </label>
<input type="username"class="form-control" name="username"></input>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="Password1" class="form-label">Password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password1" name="password">
</div>
  New user? <a href="register_new_a">Register Here</a>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-end" style="background: #0a9396" > Next</button>

</form>

</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your question. For instance show the form in `login_a.html` and also show how you register the user.

Comment: Why do you need a redirect? Can't you just change the value of the saved variable then render the page as normal?

Comment: @EneP it is best to redirect after a successful POST request to prevent accidental resubmission. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Please show the code for `DetailsForm` are you hashing the users password correctly?...

Comment: all details are being saved in the database correctly.

Comment: please indent your code especially `views.py`, it will help in identifying where you are returning the response.